# GDAL OGR OCI driver takes unreasonable long time to load from oracle database

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

For quite some time I'm trying to get OCI to work with GDAL. I created a docker image with the driver installed and I use the python api to do the work.

When I try to load and print just 20000 records it takes up to 6 minutes. This is a crazy amount of time comparing to postgres which takes just about 10 seconds.

```
from osgeo import ogr

con = "OCI:..."
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("OCI")
dataSource = driver.Open(con, 0)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

for feature in layer:
    print(feature.GetField("NAME"))

layer.ResetReading()
```

Is there a way to speed this up? I tried to google, fiddle around no luck at all. It stays slow. However if I use ogr to write to oracle it is just 12 seconds.

**Update**

I tried to work around slow read using `cx_Oracle` to retrieve data as WKT. And then I try to load data using `ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt`. This works but also takes a long time to load. The problem seems to be that ogr takes a long time to convert the WKT. In this example I try to copy a table with just 6000 records. Without WKT conversion ogr performs in 8 seconds. With WKT conversion ogr takes around 4 minutes.

```
for feature_from_wkt in cursor:
    target_feature = ogr.Feature(target_layer_defn)

    for i in range(0, target_layer_defn.GetFieldCount()):
        value = feature_from_wkt[i]

        if type(value) is datetime:
            value = value.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

        target_feature.SetField(target_layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), value)
    # When I comment this out ogr inserts the data in seconds -> how can CreateGeometryFromWkt be so slow?
    # geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(str(feature_from_wkt[-1]))
    # target_feature.SetGeometry(geom)
    target_layer.CreateFeature(target_feature)
    target_feature = None
```

Comment: Is it as slow if you read the 20000 features with ogrinfo using `-sql "select name from layer where rownum<20001"`?

Comment: Yes that also takes ~6 minutes. And it basically gets one varchar and two number fields. When I use `cx_Oracle` package it does it in just 10 seconds.

Comment: Do you have lots of tables in your database? There is a hint in the documentation "Even in databases where all desired layers are in the ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA table, it may be desirable to list only the tables to be used as this can substantially reduce initialization time in databases with many tables." Add `--debug on` to ogrinfo command, hopefully it prints out the SQL queries that it make. I suppose that it is now checking some metadata that is slow to access from Oracle. The OCI driver is by no means optimized because so few open source developers and users work with Oracle.

Comment: Well.... haha. When I select just one records it comes back in 1 second. And I select only one table in the connection string `"OCI:{oci_user}/{oci_pass}@{oci_dsn}:DDWH_4_INF_OPENDATA.INF_OD_POI_GSTATION"`.  My current project uses oracle, my workaround wil be something like using `cx_Oracle` to create a WKT dump or something like that. Just happens to be that the python bindings docu is offline https://gdal.org/python.

Comment: If one record comes in one second then the connection time cannot be the bottle neck. However I believe that GDAL can do better. I have run processes which convert millions of rows from Oracle to PostGIS in reasonable time but that was many Oracle versions ago. It is a bad sign that ogrinfo is slow but it wants to read the extent of the dataset and sometimes it must do that with SDO_AGGR_MBR. Maybe there is something else to improve in your script. See the GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_oci.py if you could find some hints.

Comment: GDAL Python API is at https://gdal.org/api/index.html#python-api.

Comment: I know about gdal.org/api/index.html#python-api but where is the good old API reference documentation. I'm looking for the overview of modules, functions, classes, fields etc. That docu was very helpful.

Comment: Send mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask. There has been a lot of activity with python docs lately https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/search?q=python+doc&type=commits. Maybe the raw version is here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/swig/include/python/docs and there it gets rendered to for example https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html.

Comment: After some investigation I implemented some code that copies table from oracle to postgres using the org API directly from python. I use WKT to extract the data and `ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt` to generate the geometry. This turns out to be very slow. When I leave the geom out it just takes a few seconds. Do you know how to speed this up?

Comment: I do not have Oracle to test with right now. My experience on GDAL and Oracle was that they can work well when user finds right tricks.

Comment: The OCI driver has two possibly interesting layer open parameters: MULTI_LOAD and MULTI_LOAD _COUNT. Those govern the use and array fetches. MULTI_LOAD should be set to YES (it should be set by default). MULTI_LOAD_COUNT should be set to the number of rows fetched in one batch. The default should be 100. Try setting that to a value like 1000. 

It may be that the doc is wrong and the default is to fetch one row at a time, which would be slow.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Since the docs are gone, do you know how I can pass these "Input dataset open option" to ogr in python? When I look at the python source code I can noty figure it out from the functions signature `def Open(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know. I assume there must be some mechanism to pass the LO and LCO options, and that should be the same for all drivers. But I have not used GDAL's Python bindings. I'm surprised that the documentation has gone ...

Comment: I just did a quick test using the `ogr2ogr2` command, to extract some 7500 geometries (all fairly complex polygons) from an Oracle database (19c) to a shapefile. That completes in a little over 3 seconds. That runs in a Linux VM on my macBook.

Comment: I tried various MULTI_LOAD settings and it made no difference. I was hoping that setting MULTI_LOAD_COUNT would slow things down a bit, but nothing changed. I also saw no traces in CPL_DEBUG output that the settings are actually being considered.

Comment: But the key thing is that the raw command line (`ogr2ogr`) looks pretty fast to me. It could be that the Python bindings of OGR introduce massive overhead ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I used the ogr2ogr commend at first. But it was slow so I programmed everything out myself to work around it. Now I'm getting `ORA-13199: wk buffer merge failure`. When I use ogr2ogr on postgres it is fast as usual. Only when reading things from oracle I get slowness. Writing to oracle is fast tho. Which version of ogr are you using? My last try is to update the OCI driver and GDAL packages. Otherwise I have to open a ticket for the oracle DBA's. I guess that ogr2ogr is slowed down under water due to ORA-13199 error.

Comment: When you continue to debug please start with new data. Create a new table, indexes etc. from some open dataset and write down the main steps you took. That way other users can reproduce the issue in their own environment. That also eliminates the possibility that there is something uncommon in your data. And if you cannot make GDAL to show the SQL that it sends to Oracle, turn on the SQL statement logging on Oracle. Some Python examples can be found from the GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_oci.py.

Comment: I'm using `GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27` I also tried with the older version: `GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14` and that works the same way: ```$ time ogr2ogr us_parks.shp          OCI:scott/tiger@localhost:1521/spatialdb:us_parks

real 0m3.077s
user 0m0.738s
sys 0m0.130s
```

Comment: All I can think of is that either your data has something specific ... Or that the hardware you use for the database is inadequate, or the network connection between your client and your database server is inadequate, or your client hardware (where you run GDAL) is inadequate ...

Comment: I'm using the Oracle-made GDAL build that is included with all 19c releases (in `$ORACLE_HOME/md/gdal`)

Comment: The  `ORA-13199: wk buffer merge failure` may be a known and fixed problem on 19c, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066764/wk-buffer-error-when-running-get-wkt-oracle-spatial-function-on-sdo-geometry-ob